# jquery mobile - how to load page properly after coming back from external link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have created JQM website where i used single page design, which means my index.html is loading first with all .js, css etc files.
My remaining pages are simple Divs with `data-role="page"`.

When i am traversing through the website then browser URL is getting changed and back button is also working.
But the problem is :

Website contains payment system and for that, user will be redirected to payment page from my website, upon success/failure, payment page is trying to redirect back to my website's last URL which will be like:

```
http://<ip>:<port>/appName/pages/page-name.html
```

but this is not loading with any css or JS files.

Is there any way i can retain the last session?
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The payment system should have a callback function where you can specify which URL to return to.

Comment: Yes it is there and from there itself i am redirecting to load the URL of my website and when i am loading the last URL of my website then it is not loading all css,js files only plain unaligned html is getting displayed.

Comment: do you have `changeHash` enabled? maybe you should build a hash like `http://<ip>:<port>/appName/pages/index.html#page-name` and return to that. here is a demo: [jQuery Mobile Hash Processing](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navigation-hash-processing/)

Comment: Yes,  i enabled it, because of which back button of browser iss navigating perfectly fine. but the comes when it is coming back from external link or if i am redirecting to the particular page.

Answer (score 0):

Within JQM you cannot directly link to a specific page within a multipage document.

The way jQuery mobile works when you link to a page with multiple pages it will default to loading the first page. You will need to use the [subpages plugin](https://github.com/ToddThomson/jQuery-Mobile-Subpage-Widget) to load the page with AJAX

You should either separate your pages or preload the multipage document via AJAX (with the plugin) and then link to it as an internal page

From the [Documentation](http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/)

> Note: You cannot link to a multipage document with Ajax navigation
>   active because the framework will only load the first page it finds,
>   not the full set of internal pages. In these cases, you must link
>   without Ajax (see next section) for a full page refresh to prevent
>   potential hash collisions. There is currently a subpage plugin that
>   makes it possible to load in multi-page documents
>
> It's important to note that if you are linking from a mobile page that
>   was loaded via Ajax to a page that contains multiple internal pages,
>   you need to add a rel="external" or data-ajax="false" to the link.
>   This tells the framework to do a full page reload to clear out the
>   Ajax hash in the URL. This is critical because Ajax pages use the hash
>   (#) to track the Ajax history, while multiple internal pages use the
>   hash to indicate internal pages so there will be conflicts in the hash
>   between these two modes.